# How to assign GUID to batches of data based on row counts and tunable batch size

Tags: sql-server, uuid, batch-processing

I need to assign batches of rows a common GUID id (for consumption by an external process).

Below is a simplified setup describing what I'm looking for:

`BASE_TABLE` represents one of pre-existing tables in this scenario, much simplified obviously.  Values in the "real" table should be considered random; they're not consecutive in real life (even the ID is not really an int)

```
CREATE TABLE BASE_TABLE (
    ID int
    ,VALUE1 varchar(10)
    ,VALUE2 varchar(255)
)
```

`TARGET_TABLE` represents the "output" of the process I'm working on, which is just the input to something else that requires batches of data to have a `uniqueIdentifier` BATCHID for each batch.  Batches in real life are ~1000 rows each.

```
CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE 
(
  ID int
  ,VALUE1 varchar(10)
  ,VALUE2 varchar(255)
  ,BATCHID uniqueIdentifier
)
```

(Add some dummy data)

```
DECLARE @DATA1 int
set @DATA1=0
WHILE @DATA1<100
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO BASE_TABLE (ID,VALUE1,VALUE2) VALUES (@DATA1,'v1'+CONVERT(varchar,@DATA1), 'v2'+CONVERT(varchar,@DATA1))
  SET @DATA1=@DATA1+1
END
```

/**
example DESIRED RESULT, with batch size of 5

| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | BATCHID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | v10 | v20 | 38B1B4FB-7F1E-44FD-9336-19095C01C629 |
| 1 | v11 | v21 | 38B1B4FB-7F1E-44FD-9336-19095C01C629 |
| 2 | v12 | v22 | 38B1B4FB-7F1E-44FD-9336-19095C01C629 |
| 3 | v13 | v23 | 38B1B4FB-7F1E-44FD-9336-19095C01C629 |
| 4 | v14 | v24 | 38B1B4FB-7F1E-44FD-9336-19095C01C629 |
| 5 | v15 | v25 | 41122454-A743-4545-8F0C-D7B461E072AE |
| 6 | v16 | v26 | 41122454-A743-4545-8F0C-D7B461E072AE |
| 7 | v17 | v27 | 41122454-A743-4545-8F0C-D7B461E072AE |
| 8 | v18 | v28 | 41122454-A743-4545-8F0C-D7B461E072AE |
| 9 | v19 | v29 | 41122454-A743-4545-8F0C-D7B461E072AE |
| 10 | v110 | v210 | 41122454-A743-4545-8F0C-D7B461E072AE |
| 11 | v111 | v211 | FBDE5513-C869-4F2D-AC4D-40CBEF4A2D48 |

etc

Important result is that for each batch of size N there are N rows with the same BatchID, which must be a GUID.

I'm pretty sure I could do what I want with a cursor, but I want to do something like this if possible:

```
select 
ID,VALUE1,VALUE2,
NEWID() OVER(PARTITION BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)) AS BatchID
from BASE_TABLE
```

but it's not valid because NEWID() isn't an aggregate function.

Comment: You want a new guod every 5,6,7,8 rows?

Comment: essentially, yes, but the solution needs to work for "new guid every 1000 rows" too -- basically I want to be able to chunk the data into batches (all the same size) but have the ability to tune the batch size

Comment: what about a stored procedure? with a loop a a runninf varoable to modolo by

Comment: I think that would work, but the input table is large, so I'm trying to avoid cursor-style looping if I can.  (might not be possible, and if not, that'll be what I do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to play with row_numbers

```
 declare @part int = 3
 
 ;with baseRowNums as 
  (
    SELECT ID, VALUE1, VALUE2,
       Row_Number() Over (ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM BASE_TABLE
  )
 ,batchNums as
 (
 SELECT *,
    Sum(CASE WHEN rn % @part = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    Over (ORDER BY ID, rn 
          ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS part
 FROM baseRowNums
 )
 ,GUIDs as
 (select part, MAX(newid()) as GUID
  from batchNums
  group by part
 )
 select ID, VALUE1, VALUE2, GUIDs.GUID
 from batchNums
 join GUIDs on batchNums.part = GUIDs.part
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c26d9bab095ce9d8ca1abf1f4c1a898